# Linq Equivalent to Where Clause with Nested Conditions

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework

The SQL Statement would like like this:

```
Select * From Table
Where 
Column1 = 'A' OR
(Column2 = 'A' AND
 Column3 = 'A')
```

So Column1 could be equal to 'A', or a combination of Column2 and Column3 equaling 'A' would constitute a match.

How could I write a linq statement to do the same thing?

Comment: it'd look pretty much exactly the same.  What have you tried doing, and what problems have you had with your attempted LINQ solution when trying to write complex predicates?

Comment: @Servy Column1 can equal A, or BOTH Column2 and Column3 TOGETHER need to equal A.

Comment: Yes, so what problems are you having with doing that in LINQ.  You'll accomplish it the same way you'd do it in SQL, by writing multiple predicates and using parenthesis.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using LINQ extension methods for `IEnumerable`:

```
var result = collection.Where(x => x.Column1 = "A" || 
                                  (x.Column2 == "A" && x.Column3 == "A"));
```

If you are using Entity Framework the you can get filtered results from your table like this:

```
using (var context = new MyDbContext())
{
    var result = cocontext.MyTable.Where(x => x.Column1 = "A" || 
                                             (x.Column2 == "A" && x.Column3 == "A"));    
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the use of lambdas being cleaner than my answer. +1

Comment: @Adam it's a preference at the end of the day. I think that your's is easier for people coming from SQL.

Answer (score 1):

It's literally exactly as it would be without the specific combination of AND/OR. Just use parentheses as necessary.

```
var query = from table in tables //or whatever your IEnumerable set is if you have one
where table.column1 == value || (table.column2 == value && table.column3 == value)
select table
```

Comment: Will this translate into a SQL Query?

Comment: This is the generic format to your query translated into LINQ. I can't be expected to implement this in your program.

Comment: @Jason if you are using EF, then it will translate it to SQL for you. LINQ to Entities is used in this case.

Comment: Unfortunately, this syntax will not work with Entity Framework i believe.

Comment: Oh I forgot my table header on the columns.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [Enity Framework](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/) and you have an entity with those properties you can do mostly the same using Linq to Entities:

```
var query= from row in context.Table
           where row.Column1 == "A" || (row.Column2 == "A" && row.Column3 == "A")
           select row;
```

Also, if you don't want to use LINQ to Entities and you want to execute directly your query, you can use the `DbSet.SqlQuery` method:

```
var result=context.Table.SqlQuery("Select * From Table Where Column1 = 'A' OR (Column2 = 'A' AND  Column3 = 'A')");
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this syntax will not work with Entity Framework i believe.